# Python 3.6 urllib TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to pull some JSON data from an API using urllib in Python 3.6. It requires header information to be passed for authorization. Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request, json

headers = {"authorization" : "Bearer {authorization_token}"}

with urllib.request.urlopen("{api_url}", data=headers) as url:
   data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
   print(data)
```

And the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getter.py", line 5, in <module>
with urllib.request.urlopen("{url}", data=headers) as url:
   File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1064, in _send_output
+ b'\r\n'
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Not too sure what's going wrong here, I'm not inputting any bytes so I'm not sure why I'm getting an error telling me I can't concat bytes to str.

Comment: I think you should use `headers=headers`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `data` argument is expected to be a bytes-like object. you need to do the following:

```
urllib.request.urlopen({api_url}, data=bytes(json.dumps(headers), encoding="utf-8"))
```

Comment: @MatthewWinfield, I've battled that problem many times. In fact this line of code was copied out of one of my projects.

Comment: My use case is an API (WebinarJam). While I didn’t get any Django/Python error, the authentication, that is done with POST data (probably not the best idea anyway, but I can’t change it), fails. With the requests library on the other hand, it worked (using the same dictionary as POST data).