# How do I use JSON to parse a website and save to a text file?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm attempting to build a function that can scrape a site and parse its content by removing tags and saving the text results into a .txt file.  The function has to pass in a header to avoid the 403 error and also bring back the entire page's content (I used Google as a proxy but the intention is for it to be any site that would potentially result in a 403 error) Here is what I have that is generating an error that reads "TypeError: can't concat str to bytes"

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.request
import json

def GetData(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
    response = urllib.request.Request(url, headers)
    with urllib.request.urlopen(response) as res:
        clean = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', res)
        data = clean.read().decode("utf-8")


    return json.loads(data)

url = ("https://google.com")
#print(GetData(url))
fileName = "Data.txt"
myFile = open(fileName, 'w')
myFile.write(GetData(url))
```

I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Here is the traceback error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "JSON.py", line 18, in 
      print(GetData(url))
      File "JSON.py", line 9, in GetData
      with urllib.request.urlopen(response) as res:
      File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37  \lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1362, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1252, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
     File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1064, in _send_output
    + b'\r\n'
    TypeError: can't concat str to bytes

Comment: Try converting the bytes to string using the `.decode()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, Maxxik CZ!  I'm rather new to programming and not too sure how to employ that function. Would you be willing to provide some guidance:)

Comment: Where exactly does the error happen? On which line exactly? Try locating the variable that contains the bytes, and do this: `variable = variable.decode()` it should convert it to string.

Comment: Thanks, I apologize for not mentioning that in my question (I edited it and added the tracback) The traceback is saying saying line 9.  I tried to set res = res.decode but it didn't change the result.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037676/python-3-6-urllib-typeerror-cant-concat-bytes-to-str)?

Comment: I did not see that.  Thanks, Maxxik CZ!  I'll follow their answer and see what happens! Appreciate your time!