# Disable ssl check in python with headers

Tags: python, ssl

I am using python and new to it. I want to hit an API given its URL. but got the some error while get the response:

```
import ssl
import json
import urllib.request


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    headers = {"X-Provider-Id": "x_jp"}
    
    conditionsSetURL = "https:xxxxxxxxxx....."
   
        
    with urllib.request.urlopen(conditionsSetURL, headers, context=ssl.SSLContext()) as url:
        print(url.read().decode('utf8'))
```

Got the issue:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "can't concat str to bytes",
  "errorType": "TypeError",
"stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 18, in lambda_handler\n    with urllib.request.urlopen(conditionsSetURL, headers, context=ssl.SSLContext()) as url:\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 222, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 525, in open\n    response = self._open(req, data)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 542, in _open\n    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 502, in _call_chain\n    result = func(*args)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 1397, in https_open\n    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py\", line 1354, in do_open\n    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1256, in request\n    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1302, in _send_request\n    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1251, in endheaders\n    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 1048, in _send_output\n    chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\\r\\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \\\n"
  ]
}
```

What is wrong here ?

EDIT: After following this[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037676/python-3-6-urllib-typeerror-cant-concat-bytes-to-str)

```
import ssl
import json
import urllib.request


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    headers = {"X-Provider-Id": "netflix_jp"}
    
    conditionsSetURL = "https:xxxxxxxxxx....."
    
    with urllib.request.urlopen({conditionsSetURL}, data=bytes(json.dumps(headers), encoding="utf-8"), context=ssl.SSLContext()) as url:
        print(url.read())
```

Error:

Response
{
"errorMessage": "'set' object has no attribute 'data'",
"errorType": "AttributeError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 22, in lambda_handler\n    with urllib.request.urlopen({conditionsSetURL}, data=bytes(json.dumps(headers), encoding="utf-8"), context=ssl.SSLContext()) as url:\n",
"  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen\n    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)\n",
"  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 513, in open\n    req.data = data\n"
]
}

Comment: Can you provide your whole stack trace? Also this question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037676/python-3-6-urllib-typeerror-cant-concat-bytes-to-str

Comment: Updated the stackTrace, Only have this... Sure will try this one also.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with SSL - the title is completely misleading.

Comment: This might not help, but try with urllib2, or requests, instead of urllib.

Comment: In short: the `headers` you gave will not be interpreted as headers but as additional data - and bytes are expected there. See the [documentation for urlopen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) about the expected arguments.