# Circular issue: Attempt to send form-url-encoded data causes TypeError: can't concat bytes to str, and the fix to latter breaks the former

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

When I try to follow the answer to this question [Python requests module sends JSON string instead of x-www-form-urlencoded param string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615756/python-requests-module-sends-json-string-instead-of-x-www-form-urlencoded-param) and pass a dict to the urlopen, I get the error described in this question: [Python 3.6 urllib TypeError: can't concat bytes to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037676/python-3-6-urllib-typeerror-cant-concat-bytes-to-str)

Code based on recommendation in answers from 1st question:

```
req = Request(url, method='POST', data={"ID": theId})
r = urlopen(req)
```

When I try to apply the accepted answer from the 2nd question and use this (similar to my original code) ...

```
urllib.request.urlopen({api_url}, data=bytes(json.dumps({"ID": theId}), encoding="utf-8"))
```

... I am right back where I started with the 1st question, as the passing of a json string in the `data` parameter forces `application/json` to be sent instead of  the `x-www-form-urlencoded` that I'm looking for:

**Is there a way out of this circular trap?**

Comment: Can you show the other version of your `urlopen` call, that gives the `bytes` related error?

Comment: Edited question, also found solution which is not mentioned in either of the linked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by calling `urllib.parse.urlencode` to convert the dict to a string, and then explicitly setting the content-type:

```
    postparam = urllib.parse.urlencode({"ID": theId}).encode('utf-8')
    req = Request(url, method='POST', data=postparam)
    req.add_header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    r = urlopen(req)
```